# How can I make two molecular particle systems collide? (Using the molecular addon)

Tags: particles, physics

I am trying to recreate something like this with the molecular addon:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7qjlWxgtNY

I created two separate particle systems, but they aren't interacting at all (when I bake the simulation, the particles go through each other). I tried to add both particle systems to the same Collision Group (as seen below) but that didn't fix anything.

[image]

I'm fairly new to blender, but I have experience in a few other programs. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully I was able to find the solution myself.

To make particle systems interact with other particle systems:

1. Go to the particle tab
2. Scroll down to "Collision:"
3. Check the box that says "Activate Collision with others"