# Replace object with another on collision

Tags: particles, collision

I'm trying to make a grass cutting animation. A blade rotates and when it collides with grass, I want to replace the grass object with the sliced variant.

I tried the particle system with 'die on hit' ticked, and to the blade I added collision with 'kill particles' ticked, but that didn't work.
But even if it worked, I still don't know how to replace them.

Sample video: https://youtu.be/YpSQlPAyW3g

Comment: You might find the (free) "Molecular" add-on useful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/69836/111042  But the documentation is AWOL.

Comment: What should happen with cuted part? Disappear from frame to frame or animate a fail? If fail where and what kind of motion?

Comment: be sure to follow this for any clues when someone comments or answers (How to cut hairs in two pieces in blender?): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181530/how-to-cut-hairs-in-two-pieces-in-blender

Comment: @vklidu Like a regular grass, it should fall down. I would like to apply physics to it.

Comment: There may be something like Hair and the python "bpy.ops.particle.brush_edit()" method to "cut" the "hair"?

Comment: I don't want to cut it, though that would be great, but too difficult. It suffices just to replace it with the sliced grass variant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### version – Boolean

Some kind of illusion can be done with boolean operation. You can start with Geometry Nodes to create grass object ...

[image]

... but final "cut" is boolean operation (grass differenced with Circle object displaced by Radial Texture), that results in glitchy anim (doesn't matter if I use boolean operation inside GN or as modifier).

[image]

What solved this is **Solidify** modifier for grass object, but in cost of viewport playback (1 fps).

[image]

Falling parts are particles emitted from Blade object ...

[image]

### version – Particles

Another illusion can be done with two exactly the same overlapping particle systems.

One with tall grass and hidden blade on plane surface level to kill particles ...

[image]

... in combination with second one identical Plane. The only difference is Render as Object with shorted grass model.

[image]

This gives you an illusion

[image]

Falling cute grass can be faked in the same way like in the first version.

[image]

Notes:

- Particles works here only because I **disabled Gravity**
- I wanted to use *Hair* system, but it didnt react on collision object *Kill Particles*.
- Another thing that doesn't work is to use blend texture controlled by another object (that is known issue)

Comment: That works great, thanks! I would also like the grass falling and possibly regrow it so it would make a nice loop, I thought about replacing the dead particle with the sliced part and the shortened grass, which would have an animation of regrowing, and after the blade hits it, it would repeat. But unfortunately I don't know how to do any of these, could you please point me it the right direction?

Comment: great idea man!!!

Comment: I stacked today with idea make it much easier and "cut" grass just by material transparency ... But I could not figure out how to apply radial gradient that could handle "regrowing" grass ... To animate cut parts can be faked simply by emitting particles from blade ... Again illusion but it could work.

Comment: It hurts my mind that blender is incapable of such a simple task... never mind, thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm not saying blender is not capable ... I have a trouble :) For someone else it can be easy-peasy ...

Comment: Updated version with Boolean operation ... I skipped details, so if you will find it useful and blend would not be self-explanatory, don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: @vklidu That works great, I also thought about a version where the grass would have a growing animation and the blade would just reset it which would perform better (using animation nodes maybe), but given my zero experience, I sticked with yours. After a few renders, [this is what I ended up with](https://youtu.be/JRbA7ge6Gbs), it looks great, except the blade particles glitch a few times, this didn't happen in the editor, have you got any idea what's happening?

Comment: Great it worked for you ... with Anim nodes I cant help, sorry :)